# zk: macro component, image src is garbage in browser, how to fix it?

Tags: zk

I was doing some R&D on macro custom component and was following the example from the demo which is http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/composite/macro_component

When I open the page in browser, the zk framework is adding garbage as image src path. If i print that path it's perfect and i get src not found for an image and I am unable to display the image on the page.

here is the sourcecode of image in browswer, look at src path ??

```
<img id="a6NTh" class="profileImg z-image" src="%7barg.img%7d">
```

my include file

includeMacroProfile.zul

```
<groupbox id="gb" mold="3d" width="310px" closable="false">
    <style>
        .desc {
            color: #008bb6;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: Times New Roman;
        }
        .detail {
            width: 200px;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .profileImg{
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
        }
    </style>
    <caption label="${empty arg.title ? 'Profile Title ': arg.title}" />
    <vlayout>
        <vlayout>
            <image class="profileImg" src="{arg.img}" />
            <label class="desc" value="${empty arg.desc ? 'Descriptions not available.': arg.desc}" />
        </vlayout>
        <textbox class="details" value="${empty arg.detail ? 'Details not available.': arg.detail}" cols="50" rows="5" readonly="true"></textbox>

    </vlayout>
</groupbox>
```

my test.zul file

```
<zk>

    <profile />
    <separator height="30px"></separator>
    <vlayout>
        <profile title="ABC" desc="This is ABC."
            detail="This is ABCfrom, Islamabad, Pakistan"
            img="/image/sample.jpg">
        </profile>
    </vlayout>

</zk>
```

could you please help me to fix it and let me know how to handle image in macro component in zk framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `$`

```
<image class="profileImg" src="{arg.img}" />
```

sould be

```
<image class="profileImg" src="${arg.img}" />
```

Comment: thank you Nabil, it's working. What happened about my other zk drag drop question ? any update???

Comment: I updated it just after I wrote the comment. So it was updated a few days ago and you did not gave me any feedback. I think you just missed it ;)

Comment: Ok, great, yes there is something new, i haven't tested that, let me test that. thanks for the help